# Ruby on Rails: link_to acting weird

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So.. here is my link_to

<%= link_to "Archive", :action => 'archive' %>

and my output in the console

```
 Parameters: {"action"=>"archive", "controller"=>"achievables"}
```

why is the action not "archive" ?
the method is defined in the controller... spelled correctly and everything.

EDIT:
from routes.rb

```
  map.archives 'achievable/archive', :controller => 'achievables', :action => 'archive'

  map.resources :achievables, :member => {:build => [:get,:post], :publish_detail => [:get,:post], :publish=>[:get,:post], :confirm_publish=>[:get,:post], :confirm_delete=>[:get,:post]}
```

right now, the error is

```
Showing app/views/layouts/build_archivable.html.erb where line #6 raised:

Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id
```

which, again, is the wrong path. =\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try specifying the action as a string rather than a symbol:

```
<%= link_to 'Archive', :action => 'archive' %>
```

Alternatively, you might have a higher priority route defined within `config/routes.rb` that is getting matched before the default `/:controller/:action/:id` route (Rails starts at the top of the file and works downwards until to hits a route that matches the URL).

Comment: how would you override that kind of routing?

Comment: @DerNalia Edit your question to show us the contents of your routes file and then I can tell you if that's the case or not.

Comment: done. I only added what I think in relevant. the routes file is 100 lines. and could be more if I had a say in the formatting.

Comment: got it, I next had to specify to use the application layout for some reason.

Comment: So is it going into the `archive` action or is it going into the `show` action? It's not clear since you edited your question.

Comment: It was going to the archive action, but was using a layout completely not related to my view, which is why I though it was going to the build action... (It really did go to show in my original)... So, I forced it to use the default layout (specified in the archive action)